# Thread gets released before the data is fetched.  Would you know why?

Tags: objective-c, ios, objective-c-blocks

I am trying to have a few different uitableviews in one viewcontroller.  With help of one of the answers here i was able to do that and setup each tableviewcontroller in separate files.  Now the issue is that the data is loading from core data and its not loading fast enough for the main tableview to show it.  i have to do reload after the data loads.  The problem is i am trying to do it automatically.  I setup a thread and when the release gets called the app crashes on the uidocument open operation.  I am not sure how to get the thread not to get release before the data finishes loading.  Here is the some of the code.

```
[self.pplTableView setDelegate:self.peopleListController]; //pplTableView is the tableview in the mainviewcontroller that shows on the screen
[self.pplTableView setDataSource:self.peopleListController];
dispatch_queue_t fetchPpl = dispatch_queue_create("pplFetch", NULL);
dispatch_async(fetchPpl, ^{
        self.peopleListController.view = self.peopleListController.tableView;
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),
                   ^{
                       [self.pplTableView reloadData];
                       NSLog(@"rows %@",[self.pplTableView numberOfSections]); 

                   });
});

dispatch_release(fetchPpl);
```

this is from the tableviewcontroller that delegating the data

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    if(!self.peopleDatabase){

        NSURL *url = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager]URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask]lastObject];

        url = [url URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Database"];
        //NSLog(@"URL ->  %@",url);
        self.peopleDatabase = [[UIManagedDocument alloc]initWithFileURL:url];
    }else {
        [self useDocument];
    }

}


-(void)useDocument{

if (self.peopleDatabase.documentState == UIDocumentStateClosed){
    [self.peopleDatabase openWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success){
        [self setupFetchResultsController];

    }];

} else if (self.peopleDatabase.documentState == UIDocumentStateNormal){
    [self setupFetchResultsController];
}
```

}

```
self.peopleListController.view = self.peopleListController.tableView;
```

When this line is getting called the controller gets loaded and useDocument is called.  It doesn't wait for the useDocument to finish to proceed.  How would i get this to wait.

Thank You!